# Calculate rotation of an object in relation to camera

Tags: geometry

I'm not a mathematician so my vocabulary may be inaccurate. Hopefully I can convey what Im trying to do. If there is a better stack for this let me know. I am working on a virtual reality project using Aframe and Three js. I have an object rendered in the virtual world. I am trying to render a minimap/heads up display in the corner of the users view so that they can see where they are in relation to the other objects in the scene. The problem I am having is that depending on what position the user is looking from, the rotation of the objects in the minimap need to change. Unfortunately, figuring out what the minimap objects rotations should be relative to the perspective of the user is beyond my mathematical knowledge. Does anyone know how I might go about this?

[The following is an image of the scene to illustrate my problem. The gray square in the top left corner is the minimap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB78D.png)

Comment: Are your trying to draw a minimap as a birdview from above (axis “up” is fixed), where the north on minimap corresponds with the direction of where camera looks?

Comment: If you know how to do this with birdview then I can definitely render it as birdview. Im not attached to birdview or "user perscpective". Whatever will make calculating this possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok, with birdview, you can do the following.
Create a new orthographic camera, put it above the main camera and make it look down  at the main camera. In addition, set the “up” vector of orthographic camera to a projection of main camera direction to the ground plane (assuming you have a standard y-axis as up axis, the projection is just setting $y$ to $0$).

In `threejs` you can do it like this:

```
    // setting `up` vector
camera.getWorldDirection(mmCamera.up);
mmCamera.up.y = 0;                       // project `up` vector to xz plane

    // setting camera position
mmCamera.position.copy(camera.position);
mmCamera.position.y = 100;               // the height of birdview camera

    // rotate camera
mmCamera.lookAt(camera.position);
```

Here is a small [demo](https://codepen.io/quokkaNut/pen/NWGJpMr) to play with.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is a good solution. I was hoping to render copy objects of the scene objects in the minimap rather than having a second camera, just to keep the minimap simpler and not make the view to garbled. This should work well though. And maybe three has a way to hide things from a camera. Thanks!